# How to match all links in python regex?

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I am trying to create a regex that matches the link from a page source. I have text formatted like this:

something here
here's a link

```
<a class="_5syj" href="https://www.here.com/FirstCal?ref=br_rs">First Cal</a><span class="mls _1ccm9 _49"></span><a class="_fasc" href="https://www.here.com/Mall?ref=br_rs">Mall</a><span class="m1ls _1cm9 _49"></span>
```

I want to get all the links that start with href="https://www.here.com/(.*)?ref=br_rs">

So from the links about, I would get either the entire link, or FIrstCal and Mall (from the link)

Python code:

```
regex = r'(?<=href="https://www.here.com/).*(?<=?ref=br_rs)'

link = re.findall(regex, str(source))

link
```

But it's not working.

Any ideas ?

**PS: Regex would be the only way to do this. A html parse won't work because the website is not "stable" with it's structure.**

Comment: Obligatory reference: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

Comment: Don't go there, use a HTML parser instead and make your life that much easier. Regular expressions are not the best tool for HTML parsing.

Comment: I know, but I am trying to scrape a website, that changes it's div ids,classes very often, so the only way that I could go is regex. I would like a html parser, but I can't here

Comment: BeautifulSoup can handle this case easily, by applying regular expressions to the attribute values only. `soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('https://www.here.com/.*?ref=br_rs'))` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup with a regular expression matching just the `href` contents:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('https://www.here.com/.*?ref=br_rs'))
```

The parser won't care that the structure is changing, you just need to be precise about what *is* stable; the links.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <a class="_5syj" href="https://www.here.com/FirstCal?ref=br_rs">First Cal</a><span class="mls _1ccm9 _49"></span><a class="_fasc" href="https://www.here.com/Mall?ref=br_rs">Mall</a><span class="m1ls _1cm9 _49"></span>
... ''')
>>> soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('https://www.here.com/.*?ref=br_rs'))
[<a class="_5syj" href="https://www.here.com/FirstCal?ref=br_rs">First Cal</a>, <a class="_fasc" href="https://www.here.com/Mall?ref=br_rs">Mall</a>]
```

Comment: I cannot install BeautifulSoup. I am trying to install it with pip3.3 for python 3.3, but I get an error that unit tests have failed.

Comment: What's the error? Can you copy paste it for us? Thanks! :)

Comment: @icebox19: what is the error there? I have had no problems installing BeautifulSoup on Python 3.3 with pip.

Comment: @icebox19: you are installing BeautifulSoup 3, which is not compatible with Python 3. Install BeautifulSoup 4 instead: `pip3.3 install beautifulsoup4`.